# ruby on rails - git push heroku master stop on "remote: Building source: "

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

On "git push heroku master" the deploy stop on "remote: Building source" according image bellow.

Any body can help me?

[image]

My gem file:

```rb
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.5.7'

gem "font-awesome-rails"

gem "nested_form"

# To paginate
gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.1.0'

# Jquery
gem 'jquery-rails'

# Autenticate user
gem 'devise'

#gem to mask the inputs
gem 'jquery_mask_rails', '~> 0.1.0'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.3'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.4.1'
end
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of chromedriver to run system tests with Chrome
  gem 'chromedriver-helper'
end

 gem 'wdm', '>= 0.1.0'


ruby '2.5.7'
```

In the previous deploy I used a version of ruby and rails different from the version in which I am trying to deploy. Does this have anything to do with the problem?

Comment: Same problem here. Heroku has issues. According to https://status.heroku.com/ there is a problem with "Dynos and Builds Failing - US Common Runtime"

Comment: my 2cents - be patient and watch the status page at heroku - I suggest do not start changing YOUR code - the problem is most likely heroku - I've been here a dozen time plus with heroku - I am ALSO having the same problem - everything previous push okay, then made minor grammar changes and received the same error you did... it's not my code - be patient

Comment: ALL FIXED FOR ME - try a fresh git push to heroku